# Find ID's that only have a status of 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query that brings back all rg_id's that only have a status of 0. As an example, rg_id 7 & 23 have a status of 0 & 1 so I don't want these to be included in the result.

[image]

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY HAVING

Comment: what you have tried for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can ensure that all `status` values in each group have no other values than `0` using `having` with `sum`:

```
select `rg_id` 
from `tbl`
group by `rg_id`
having sum(`status` <> 0) = 0
```

Comment: Worked perfectly mate.

Answer (score 4):

Try with group by:

```
select id, sum(status)
from tablename
group by id
having sum(status)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists` if you have status only `0` & `1` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.status = 0 and
      not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.rg_id = t.rg_id and t1.status = 1);
```

Other option is to use `group by` clause :

```
select rg_id
from table t
group by rg_id
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 0;
```

Comment: The second option worked for me mate but first didn't.

Answer (score 0):

use not in with conditional aggregation

```
select * from t where
 rg_id not in(   select rg_id 
                  from t 
                  where status in (0,1)
                  group by rg_id
                 having count(distinct status)=2 
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Minus, if you want only 0 ( not id have both 0 & 1)

select id from table1 where status = 0
Minus
select id from table1 where status = 1